# Redux dispatch in useEffect causes numerous redux errors

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

**Edit - Fixed** The problem was absolute garbage redux code as it was my first time using it. I studied Redux and rewrote my code and it works fine. It wasn't working because there was way too much garbage code working at once.

I'm using nextJS and when visiting a shared URL such as /username/p/postID I want to display the initial post modal/popover.

```
    async function presentInitialPost(postID: string) {
        const postSnap = await db.collection("posts").doc(postID).get();
        const postData = postSnap.data();
        if(postData){
            dispatch(showModalPostView(postData as Post));
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if(initialPostID){
            presentInitialPost(initialPostID)
        }
    }, [initialPostID])
```

Errors (there ae numerous of each):
"You may not unsubscribe from a store listener while the reducer is executing."
"You may not call store.getState() while the reducer is executing."

I use the same dispatch throughout my app just fine - and if I call `presentInitialPost` on a button click instead - it works completely fine.

I've tried delays and debugging where the error is coming from but I haven't figured it out at all, any help is appreciated, thank you.

Redux code:

```
showModalPostView(state, action) {
  state.showModalPostViewFunction(action.payload);
},

setShowModalPostViewFunction(state, action) {
  state.showModalPostViewFunction = action.payload;
  return state;
},

showModalPostViewFunction: (post: Post) => {},
```

`showModalPostViewFunction` comes from my overlay wrapper component

```
    showModalPostView = (post: Post) => {
        console.log(this.state)
        this.setState({
            showModalPostView: true,
            modalPostViewPost: post,
        });
    };
```

When the modal post view is shown here, it contains multiple `useSelector`s which cause the errors - but only when i present the modal post view in useEffect - it works just fine throughout the app when dispatched through a click action.

In modal post view various selectors throw the errors:

```
const likedPosts = useSelector((state: ReduxRootState) => state.likedPosts);
```

Comment: Can you share the actual error message(s)?

Comment: @Jacob They're in the question: "You may not call store.getState() while the reducer is executing." "You may not unsubscribe from a store listener while the reducer is executing."

Comment: It sounds like an issue in your reducer then; can you post your reducer code?

Comment: @Jacob I just did, I think the issue might have to do with react strict modes double render calling the useSelectors twice, but I just can't figure it out. Everything works fine if I remove the useSelectors in the modal view itself

Comment: Does calling `presentInitialPost(initialPostID)` further update `initialPostID`?

Comment: `showModalPostView` does not appear to be an action creator... it's setting state, not returning an action to be sent to your reducer. You should dispatch an action and let the reducer modify the state. Perhaps you didn't mean to use `dispatch()` at all?

Comment: @PrajwalKulkarni no, the postID and URL are not changed when calling presenting the modal.

Comment: @Jacob `showModalPostView ` is a function in the slice's state set from another dispatch. It's not the optimal setup as it was my first time with redux, but it works perfectly unless used in a useEffect the Modal component seems to double render causeing the useSelector to be called twice, causing the errors. Is there any hack to prevent the double render in this case?

Comment: Since you're saying it works well elsewhere but causes problems only in `useEffect`, possibly the `dispatch` function is called more than once, try calling the `presentInitialPost(initialPostID)` without any dependency values in `useEffect`

Comment: @PrajwalKulkarni I tried this already and have the same issue, although I do think the problem is caused by a double render. Just can't figure out the cause.

Comment: Is this component where you're performing the dispatch action a child of another component? Note that if there's a double render occurring, some prop value might've changed in the parent component, causing the child component to re-render. If that's the case you might want to use something like `useCallback`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are not using redux the way it was intended to be used. What you pass to `dispatch()` is supposed to be an *action*. A reducer receives that action and returns new state, and then then new state is sent to your subscriber (the React component).

You are instead calling a *function* `showModalPostView` which is calling some `setState` function in the parent component and is returning who knows what. That return value is being passed as an argument `dispatch`, which kicks off a reducer. However, that `setState` is likely causing your child component to unsubscribe from the store so it can re-render.

It like you aren't actually dispatching an action; you're just calling a function, so you shouldn't be using `dispatch` at all.

```
async function presentInitialPost(postID: string) {
    const postSnap = await db.collection("posts").doc(postID).get();
    const postData = postSnap.data();
    if(postData){
        showModalPostView(postData as Post);
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the redux knowledge and am going to study this and spend the day rewriting my redux code completely. Although dispatch is required here as without neither the function in the state, or the one that replaces via another dispatch from the overlay wrapper gets called. When importing `showModalPostView` it shows the type as `ActionCreatorWithPayload<any, string>`, not a function.

Comment: An action creator is a function that , but the `showModalPostView` function you posted isn't returning an action. Based on that name, it looks like you're using _redux toolkit_ which I'm not familiar with. Will add a tag to your question to hopefully catch experts in that library since this does not look like vanilla redux.